# Error while installing Anaconda

Tags: python, directory, anaconda

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit
       Python 2.7.12

I am installing Anaconda 5.2 for Python 2.7 version,and I am always getting this error:

`[/home/nvidia/anaconda2] >>> nvidia/anaconda3
PREFIX=/home/nvidia/nvidia/anaconda3
installing: python-2.7.15-h1571d57_0 ...
Anaconda2-5.2.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 370: /home/nvidia/nvidia/anaconda3/pkgs/python-2.7.15-h1571d57_0/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

I tried to change directory, it didn't work ?
I tried different versions of the Anaconda, it didn't work ?

Comment: (1) You are on 64-bit x86_64, not 64-bit ARM or POWER or something, right? (2) Can you verify the hash of the download, or just repeat the download and try again, to make sure this isn't just the result of a corrupted or truncated download?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to run `anaconda3` to install Anaconda for 2.7? Also, why are you trying to run the binary instead of executing the shell script [as shown in the help](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux)?

Comment: Anaconda3 is just a directory that I specified for anaconda2. Because once it gave an error, the second time I tried to install in anaconda2 directory, I got warning: this directory exists and I can't install it here.

Comment: @abarnert thank you, I just realized this. I am using jetson TX 2, maybe it is different for Jetson.

Comment: Also @abarnert. Thank you for the link. I was following a person in youtube, to get it done easier. But I think it was a big mistake

Comment: I've never used a Jetson, but yeah, according to [the tech spec](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems-dev-kits-modules/), it has "HMP Dual Denver 2/2 MB L2 + 
Quad ARM® A57/2 MB L2", which I'm pretty sure are both ARM8 processors. But a simpler way to check this is to run `uname -p` or `-m` or `-i`. If those don't say `x86_64`, you can't install x86-64 software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your core problem is that you're trying to install software compiled for the x86_64 processor, but you have ARM8 processors. (According to [the tech specs for the Jetson TX2](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems-dev-kits-modules/), it has [HMP Dual Denver 2/2 MB L2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Denver) and [Quad ARM® A57/2 MB L2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A57).)

The fact that they're both 64-bit doesn't make any difference; they're still radically different process architectures, with different instruction sets, so they can't run each other's code.

And that's why you get `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.

---

From what I understand, Anaconda only provides supported installers for a handful of linux platforms—x86_64, x86, and POWER.

And I'm not aware of anyone providing third-party ported binary installers.

However, it should be possible to build Anaconda, or at least Miniconda, from source.

For example, [this site](https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-Anaconda:-Building-Miniconda-3) explains how to build it for IBM Z-Series computers running Ubuntu, which probably isn't too different from what you'd need to do.

- Keep in mind that this is apparently just some guy's project, not official Anaconda, so there's no guarantees it's all correct and up-to-date.
- You need to use whatever your platform says for `uname` instead of `s390x`.
- There probably won't be prebuilt packages in Conda and Conda-Forge for your platform, so installing things may take a lot longer and fail a bit more often.
- You may need to explicitly disable Intel MKL for source builds.

I don't *think* anything else is likely to be a problem, but I haven't tried anything remotely similar.

---

Alternatively, you could just use Ubuntu's Python, and manage your Python packages with the traditional combination of `apt-get` and `pip`.